# Reordering x axes on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Im trying to do a demographic pyramid, but when I do the ggplot, the groups reorder in a different way, for example the 5 to 9 old go way up, as you can see in the following example.

```
demo=demo %>% arrange(factor(Grupos, levels = c('0-4 años', '5-9 años', '10-14 años', '15-19 años', '20-24 años', '25-29 años', '30-34 años','35-39 años','40-44 años','45-49 años','50-54 años','55-59 años','60-64 años','65-69 años','70-74 años','75-79 años','80-84 años','85+')))


library(ggplot2)
library(lemon)

popchart=ggplot(demo, aes(x = Grupos, y = Valor, fill = Grupo)) + 
  geom_bar(data = subset(demo, Grupo == "Mujer"), stat = "identity") +
  geom_bar(data = subset(demo, Grupo == "Hombre"), stat = "identity") + 
  scale_y_symmetric(labels = abs) +
  coord_flip()
```

Giving to me the following output

[image: Graph1]

And idea how to fix it?

Comment: You change the levels of `Grupos` but didn't overwrite the old one. Try `demo <- demo %>% mutate(Grupos = factor(Grupos, levels = c(...))) %>% arrange(Grupos)`

Comment: @DarrenTsai That change the value of `Grupos` to NA :(

Comment: Because those levels you assign to `Grupos` in `factor()` do not exist in `Grupos`. E.g. `factor(1:3, levels = c('a', 'b', 'c'))` also converts `1:3` to `NA`. You are doing somthing like this.

Answer (score 1):

ggplot orders variables according to factor levels, not according to the order of rows in the data set. Your code hasn't actually saved the factor level-ordering of `Grupos`. You should probably use `mutate` to do this. I'm going to give a slightly abbreviated version because I don't have your data set and I'm lazy. Suppose the levels in your `Grupos` variable are "0 a 4", "5 a 9", "10 a 14", "15+".

```r
level_vec <- c("0 a 4", "5 a 9", "10 a 14", "15+")
label_vec <- c('0-4 años', '5-9 años', '10-14 años', '15+ años')
demo <- demo %>% 
    mutate(across(Grupos, factor, levels = level_vec, labels = label_vec))
```

Provided that your levels are in order in the original data set, you could probably also use `mutate(across(Grupos, forcats::fct_inorder))`; that won't get you the nice labels, but it will save you writing out the levels vector.

Comment: that convertí all the data of `Grupos` in NA